# number of unlabelled graphs on n vertices

Tags: graph, graph-theory

Can someone tell me or prove the formula for number of simple **unlabelled** undirected connected graphs possible on n vertices ?

Comment: IMHO this belongs on https://math.stackexchange.com/, not on SO.

Comment: http://oeis.org/A000088